# Connection to ec2 instance closed by remote host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

After a day of creating instance trying to access the server is closing the connection automatically. May i know the reason.

Comment: i  tried all this but not working

Comment: Does the connection start, but then you are thrown out at random intervals? If so, it is normally a result of network instability. You can experiment by trying a different network to see if it is the cause (eg home vs office vs tethered via phone).

Comment: I am using a wired connection its fast.

Comment: Is your instance healthy? Maybe its running out of ram or disk space?

Comment: memory is there. Its newly created.

Comment: I _HIGHLY_ recommend you try via another network connection. Sometimes corporate networks block certain types of traffic. The error is normally an indication of network instability.